# Calculate Top N products by sales and years

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, calculated-columns, algebra

I have the data about sales by years and by-products, let's say like this:

```
Year <- c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
Model <- c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e")
Sale <- c("30","45","23","33","24","11","56","19","45","56","33","32","89","33","12")
df <- data.frame(Year, Model, Sale)
```

product by years:

> ```
> a= 30+11+33 = 74
> b= 45+56+32 = 133
> c= 23+19+89 = 131
> d= 33+45+33 = 111
> e= 12+56+24 = 92
> ```

Ranking by according to total sales within these 3 years:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
b c d e a
```

I want the code which identifies the TOP 2 products (according to total sales within these 3 years) by years and summarises all the rest products as category "other". So the output should be like this:

> ```
> year     Model          Sale
> 2010      b              45
> 2010      c              23
> 2010      other          30+33+24=92
> 2011      b              56
> 2011      c              19
> 2011      other          11+45+56=112
> 2012      b              32
> 2012      c              89
> 2012      other          33+33+12= 78
> ```

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far and why didn't it meet your requirements?

Comment: I have written output by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **tidyverse** solution. Your `Sale` data appear to be stored as character, which means we'll have to use `as.numeric` before summing them.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Model) %>% 
  mutate(
    Sale = as.numeric(Sale),
    total_sale = sum(Sale)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(
    model_condensed = ifelse(total_sale %in% rev(sort(unique(total_sale)))[1:2], Model, 'other')
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Year, model_condensed) %>% 
  summarize(Sale = sum(Sale))

   Year model_condensed  Sale
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1  2010 b                  45
2  2010 c                  23
3  2010 other              87
4  2011 b                  56
5  2011 c                  19
6  2011 other             112
7  2012 b                  32
8  2012 c                  89
9  2012 other              78
```

The above solution creates the "other" category by matching on the values in `Sale`. This could cause problems if those values have decimal places (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)). Instead, we could use a two-step process to identify the top two Models by name, and use this to create the groupings for the total data:

```
totals <- df %>% 
  group_by(Model) %>% 
  summarize(total_sale = sum(as.numeric(Sale))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_sale)) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 2)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year, model_condensed = ifelse(Model %in% totals$Model, Model, 'other')) %>% 
  summarize(Sale = sum(as.numeric(Sale)))
```

Comment: Can you help me to identify the TOP N model based on each year not from the accumulated total sale? I can open new question if you want

Comment: Probably best to post as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941494/how-to-increase-speed-efficiency-of-code